# How to send SMS programmatically using IOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

I am triyng to make an application who can send SMS programmatically using IOS simulator.
Can some please please tell me what are the sequence of steps.
What is code and how we can use it step by step with details.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to send sms through any gateway right? or you want to send it programmatically ?

Comment: iOS simulator can't send SMS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ios similator can not send messages but you can send it by running your project in divice by using this code.

Add MessageUI framework in your project

Then in your .h file add this

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface MessageViewController : UIViewController<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)SendTextBtnTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

And in your .m file add this

```
- (IBAction)SendTextBtnTapped:(id)sender {
    [self sendSMS:@"" recipientList:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil]];
}

//for sms

- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = bodyOfMessage;    
        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        controller.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }    
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
        NSLog(@"Message sent");  
    else 
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
}
```

Comment: Can u send sms by iOS simulator?

Comment: use divice to send msg.

Comment: but he wants to send sms by iOS simulator not by device

Comment: I said in starting of my answer that he can not send msg from simulator but using this code he can send msg by adding his project in divice.

Comment: @Sudha there is no way to send sms from simulator bcoz sms service use SIM message center which simulator does not contain.